# git pull interprets git@ as username

Tags: git, gitlab

I can use `git pull` just fine with the `https://server/project.git` syntax. It asks my username and then that users's password. However, when I specify the origin with `git@server:project.git`, as gitlab suggests, I get `git@server's password:`, I don't get the chance to type in my username. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `user@host:/path/to/file` is the standard format.  If you need to use a different user then your remote should be `<user>@server:project.git`.

Comment: If you need some other user name, just provide that other name, as @0x5453 suggests. Note that you can also use the syntax `ssh://user@host/project.git` for symmetry with the `https://` syntax; I usually do.

Comment: That gives me permission denied with the same password with which I can log in via the gitlab web frontend

Comment: `git` is the user name. That form is intended for use with public-key encryption, where (I believe this is how it works) everyone authenticates as `git`, but using a private key associated with a public key specific to their account.